# Difference in SHA hashes between ruby and C#

Tags: c#, ruby, hash, sha256

I'm developing an application, that makes use of some REST web services.
It's technical documentation says that I should pass SHA256 hash of some string in the request.

In an example request (in the documentation) a string:

> hn-Rw2ZHYwllUYkklL5Zo_7lWJVkrbShZPb5CD1expires=1893013926label[0]=any/somestatistics=1d,2d,7d,28d,30d,31d,lifetimestatus=upl,livetitle=a

After executing:

```
digest = Digest::SHA256.digest(string_to_sign)
signature = Base64::encode64(digest).chomp.gsub(/=+$/, '')
```

results in a hash:

> YRYuN2zO+VvxISNp/vKQM5Cl6Dpzoin7mNES0IZJ06U

This example is in ruby, as the documentation is for ruby developers.

I'm developing my application in C# and for the exactly same string, when I execute:

```
byte[] rawHash = sha256.ComputeHash(rawRequest, 0, rawRequest.Length);
string friendlyHash = Convert.ToBase64String(rawHash);
```

and remove the trailing "=" signs, I get:

> Vw8pl/KxnjcEbyHtfNiMikXZdIunysFF2Ujsow8hyiw

and therefore, the application fails to execute resulting in an signature mismatch error.

I've tried changing the encoding while converting the string to a byte array preceding the hashing and nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you trimmed the string?  Might be a space in there somewhere.

Comment: Can you send us the string you are using. I can not replicate your results in ruby either..

Comment: Rayan, what is the result of hashing in your try in ruby?

Comment: stimms, nope, trimming don't change anything.

Comment: FYI, with Python I'm getting RuVTyg6Wc5vL51Z4goeRGAqTdb1ioHknFihtyRzKlvw -- curiouser and curiouser, said Alice...

Comment: Alex, well, I copied the string into my app and gave me the same results. It is because stackoverflow.com added newlines and whitespace chars to what I've written. Now I've corrected the question and still having the old result.

Comment: irb> p Base64::encode64(Digest::SHA256.digest("hn-Rw2ZHYwllUYkklL5Zo_ 7lWJVkrbShZPb5CD1expires=1893013926label[0]=any/somestatistics= 1d,2d,7d,28d,30d,31d,lifetimestatus=upl,livetitle=a")).chomp.gsub(/=+$/, '')
"RuVTyg6Wc5vL51Z4goeRGAqTdb1ioHknFihtyRzKlvw"

Comment: Uh, I meant: irb> p Base64::encode64(Digest::SHA256.digest("hn-Rw2ZHYwllUYkklL5Zo_7lWJVkrbShZPb5CD1expires=1893013926label[0]=any/somestatistics=1d,2d,7d,28d,30d,31d,lifetimestatus=upl,livetitle=a")).chomp.gsub(/=+$/, '')
"Vw8pl/KxnjcEbyHtfNiMikXZdIunysFF2Ujsow8hyiw"

Comment: Your test string is wrong.
The documentation uses hn-Rw2ZH-YwllUYkklL5Zo_7lWJVkrbShZPb5CD1expires=1893013926label[0]=any/somestatistics=1d,2d,7d,28d,30d,31d,lifetimestatus=upl,livetitle=a

Comment: Are the bytes from the SHA256.digest() call and the bytes from the sha256.ComputeHash() call the same? Maybe you can narrow the problem to either the has or the base 64 encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the document [here](http://www.ooyala.com/api/OoyalaPartnerAPI.pdf), you are missing a - (that is a dash) in your string.  Seems that Acrobat helpfully removes it in a copy paste from the document...

Here is some code that I splatted together that gets the same value as the example (well it would if you trimmed the final =)

```
    string s = "hn-Rw2ZH-YwllUYkklL5Zo_7lWJVkrbShZPb5CD1expires=1893013926label[0]=any/somestatistics=1d,2d,7d,28d,30d,31d,lifetimestatus=upl,livetitle=a";

    SHA256Managed sh = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] request = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    sh.Initialize();
    byte[] b4bbuff = sh.ComputeHash(request, 0, request.Length);

    string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(b4bbuff);
```

Comment: What you said. I should probably have put that in an answer.